# CredentialRetrievalError within ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, credentials

#### Problem

I have deployed an ECS cluster and am running a job orchestration platform on the cluster. One of the containers of this platform uses the python docker api to pull a container from our private ECR repo and execute a job within the container. When the job starts running, it eventually hits an issue where it cannot find the assume role credentials defined inside the container in `/root/.aws/config` as `credential_source=EcsContainer`. This happens after the code tries to make a call to S3.

Why might this happening? The credential source is defined in the container. Why is it not found?

#### Details

##### Error

```
......

The above exception was caused by the following exception:
botocore.exceptions.CredentialRetrievalError: Error when retrieving credentials from EcsContainer: No credentials found in credential_source referenced in profile default
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 42, in solid_execution_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/utils/__init__.py", line 383, in iterate_with_context
    next_output = next(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dagster/core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 65, in _coerce_solid_compute_fn_to_iterator
    result = fn(context, **kwargs) if context_arg_provided else fn(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/dagster/app/solids/files.py", line 33, in stream_url_to_s3
    with smart.open(f's3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_key}', 'wb', transport_params=tp) as s3location:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 235, in open
    binary = _open_binary_stream(uri, binary_mode, transport_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 398, in _open_binary_stream
    fobj = submodule.open_uri(uri, mode, transport_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/s3.py", line 224, in open_uri
    return open(parsed_uri['bucket_id'], parsed_uri['key_id'], mode, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/s3.py", line 308, in open
    writebuffer=writebuffer,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/s3.py", line 757, in __init__
    _initialize_boto3(self, client, client_kwargs, bucket, key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/s3.py", line 528, in _initialize_boto3
    client = boto3.client('s3', **init_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 91, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 826, in create_client
    credentials = self.get_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 431, in get_credentials
    'credential_provider').load_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1962, in load_credentials
    creds = provider.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1395, in load
    return self._load_creds_via_assume_role(self._profile_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1410, in _load_creds_via_assume_role
    role_config, profile_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1566, in _resolve_source_credentials
    credential_source, profile_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1623, in _resolve_credentials_from_source
    'in profile %s' % profile_name
```

##### Configuration

Container Role:

```yaml
  EcsTaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Description: The role assumed by the containers, allowing them to call AWS services.
      RoleName: !Sub ecs-task-trans-role-development
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: !Sub 's3-access-${EnvironmentName}-${AWS::StackName}'
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Resource:
              - "*"
```

`/root/.aws/config` in the container:

```
[default]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<my account>:role/ecs-task-trans-role-development
credential_source = EcsContainer
```

There is no `/root/.aws/credentials` file because the point of assuming a role from the config file is to retrieve the temporary credentials.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html

Partial `TaskDefinition`:

```yaml
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ...
      ContainerDefinitions:
          ...
          MountPoints:
            - ContainerPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
              SourceVolume: docker_sock
              ReadOnly: true
            - ContainerPath: "/root/.docker"
              SourceVolume: docker_dir
              ReadOnly: true
            - ContainerPath: "/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login"
              SourceVolume: docker_creds
              ReadOnly: true
```

#### What I have tried

1. Use the `taskExecutionRole` rather than the container role.
2. Exporting `AWS_PROFILE=default` in the container